# Is there any additional sealing operation required after grouting for the bath shower

Tags: bathroom, shower, waterproofing, sealing, grout

For re-grouting the bath shower, is there any additional sealing operation (like using sealant) after applying un-sanded grout on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Portland cement based grout benefit from a sealer.  I prefer the distillate based sealers, but I hear good things regarding the newer water based sealers.

One grout type doesn't need any sealer: 2 part epoxy grout.  A bit more care and effort during install, but nearly bullet proof afterwards.  Shower floors and foyers really stay clean.

Comment: I bought POLYBLEND Ceramic Tile Caulk for a small area of re-caulk operation. If I still need to apply waterproof seal on it after my re-caulking, could you recommend one selant? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I prefer the Miracle Sealant line, but TileLab or Aquamix should be adequate.  I wish I could point you to a scientific review, but I've only ever seen anecdotal ones (like mine).

Comment: Herrbag is telling you right, As well as the sealant. Pretty much all the tile subcontractors we use seals the joints with Porous Plus 511 by Miracle Sealant. There is a version that is a color enhancer, and another that leaves the joints the same, please use the latter of the two. Do not leave it on the surface too long, a few minutes only before wiping/buffing it with a dry towel